# Managing private heaps

Tags: c, linux, heap-memory

I see in certain projects(Basically many embedded applications in C/C++), where they manage dynamic allocations as follows

- Acquire a huge chunk of memory during initialization (based on the need).This region is designated to be the Heap for that application.
- All the dynamic allocations across different routines are made within this memory via the wrappers that are designed for allocation and maintenance (tracking and debugging allocations).

**Questions:**

Q1: Advantages of the above mentioned design of having a private heap management.

Q2: Is there any built-in function in C,Linux API's that offer interfaces to do dynamic allocation within the previously allocated chunk. I searched through it, but couldn't get a grip of it

Q3: If option mentioned in Q2 isn't available. Any thoughts of how the objective mentioned in Q2 can be accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

As you are saying that **Basically many embedded applications in C/C++** uses different approach to get dynamic memory as you have defined.

i think it is done basically availability of less memory & for proper use.

if you try to get insight how malloc() or calloc() functions work in c for dynamic memory allocation then you will get certainly the answer. i can explain a little bt as...
 **What it(malloc) really does is maintain a linked list of free memory.But Initially, the free list is empty. When the first malloc() is called, we call sbrk() to get a new chunk of memory for the free list. This memory is split up so that some is returned to the user, and the rest goes back onto the free list.There will be a global variable malloc_head, which is the head of the free list. When malloc() is called, it looks on its list for a piece of memory that is big enough. If it finds one, then it removes that memory from the linked list and returns it to the user. When free() is called, the memory is put back on the linked list. Now, to be efficient, if there is a chunk of memory on the free list that much bigger than what is requested, then it breaks up that chunk into two chunks -- one which is the size of the request (padded to a multiple of 8), and the remainder. The remainder is put on the free list and the one the size of the request is returned to the user.**

for detailed information try to refer http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~huangj/cs360/360/notes/Malloc2/lecture.html
http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~huangj/cs360/360/notes/Malloc1/lecture.html

**question1->** now for ur first question the advantage may be saving of memory & allocation in more efficient manner which depends on the project which is implementing their way.

**question2->** i haven't seen any builtin library or API in c to do so.

**question3->** for inplementation of ur own API u need to refer the given link & R&K book for C. this book explains much more in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Q1:

1. *Performance* - after the heap has been allocated (normally done during initialization), all future allocations from it are extremely fast, it's mainly just a bit of pointer arithmetic inside the heap.
2. *Fragmentation* - single allocation of large memory chunk prevents memory fragmentation due to multiple allocs/deallocs.
3. *Control* - having all memory available makes the system more robust. This can be important in situations where allocation failure is unacceptable.

Preallocated memory is closely related to the concept of look-aside lists.

Q2:

I'm not aware of such API in C but in C++ there's actually built-in operator that can assist with implementation - see [Placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).
Such utility should be fairly easy to implement in C as well.

Q3:

For example (very high-level):

1. Allocate the memory.
2. Create a heap structure of free space chunks inside the memory (initially it will contain a single chunk representing the entire memory).
3. Create a heap structure of occupied chunks of memory (initially it will be empty).
4. On allocation - traverse the heap and find chunk of appropriate size; remove it from the heap and populate with the new data. Calculate the remaining memory in the chunk and reinsert it into the heap. The occupied chunk insert into the heap of occupied chunks.
5. On freeing - remove the chunk from the occupied chunks heap and insert it into the free memory heap.